# How can i filter before render page?

Tags: python, django, filter, view

I want to filter some objects through sector.

Here is my model:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Brand Name", blank=False, null=True)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Sector Name", blank=False, null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/")
```

And this is my view where i want to filter it:

```
def automotive(request):
    videos = Videos.objects.filter()
```

The thing is in my navbar i've few sector names. When user clicks one, it should render video with sector name that user clicked.
For example, one of my sector name is Automotive. So when i click that, i should see videos that only sector is Automotive.

So sorry for my broken English, i tried my best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i added my own choices for sector in model like;

```
sectors = (
    ("FMCG", "FMCG"),
    ("Retail", "Retail"),
    ("E-Commerce", "E-Commerce")
)
```

And i gave parameter for filtering in view like;

```
def retail(request):
   videos = Videos.objects.filter(sector="Retail")
   return render(request, 'home.index.html', {'videos': videos})
```

It worked.